# What is the pygetwindow module used for?

Tags: python

Was just wondering what is the pygetwindow module used for? Are there other modules that are similar to pygetwindow? Where could i read up on pygetwindow, i can find no tutorials on it on youtube or anything.

Comment: As said on PyPI, the module is still in developement. Therefore the [documentation](https://pygetwindow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is minimal, if it can even be called that way.

Answer (score 1):

its used for window management

some simple use case (tested on windows 10):

```
import pygetwindow
import time
import os

z1 = pygetwindow.getAllTitles()
time.sleep(1)
print(len(z1))
# add some app or folder name here
os.startfile("C:\\Users\\NAME\\PATH")
time.sleep(1)
z2 = pygetwindow.getAllTitles()
print(len(z2))
time.sleep(1)
# identifies new window
z3 = [x for x in z2 if x not in z1]
z3 = ''.join(z3)
print(z3)
time.sleep(3)
# selected window manipulation 
y = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle(z3)[0]
y.resizeTo(450, 750)
y.moveTo(800, 0)
time.sleep(3)
y.activate()
y.resizeTo(750, 650)
```

Answer (score -2):

I test the sample on the Win10
y.active() return the erroe code below:
PyGetWindowException: Error code from Windows: 0